# Determine Oracle Warehouse Builder version

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-warehouse-builder

Is there a way to check whether a server is running the *11g release 2* or *11g release 1* version of Oracle Warehouse Builder?

Also is it safe to assume that `Release 11.1.0.7.0` in terms of the Oracle instance itself (as opposed to OWB) is an instance of *11g release 1*?

```
select * from v$version;
```

returns

```
Oracle Database 11g Enterprise Edition Release 11.1.0.7.0 - 64bit Production
PL/SQL Release 11.1.0.7.0 - Production
CORE    11.1.0.7.0  Production
TNS for Solaris: Version 11.1.0.7.0 - Production
NLSRTL Version 11.1.0.7.0 - Production
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Also is it safe to assume that Release 11.1.0.7.0 in terms of the Oracle instance itself (as opposed to OWB) is an instance of 11g release 1?"

Yes.

To get the version of OWB, try...

```
select release
from   all_iv_installations;
```

(I can't test it as I haven't got OWB installed.)

Ref:  http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E10926_01/doc/owb.101/b12146/d_pub.htm

---

Given that the OWB schema is installed with the database, it seems likely that that's the version of OWB you'll have, unless you think it's been upgraded seperately.

It seems it is possible to install OWB 11.2 into an 11.1 database:

"It is generally not necessary to download this standalone software unless you have any of the following needs:
- To install OWB 11.2 and host an OWB repository on Oracle Database 10 g Release 2 or Oracle Database 11 g Release 1. "

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/warehouse/downloads/index.html

Answer (score 1):

Log onto the owb server and the following query should help you:

```
 select runtime_version from owbsys.wb_rt_service_nodes;
```

You either need to log in as owbsys or as someone who has the privileges to access this table.